# dispatcher-servlet: Invalid content was found starting with element 'repositories'

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm trying to use:

```
<repositories base-package="com.site.cmt.repositories" repository-impl-postfix="">
    <repository id="variableRepository" />
</repositories>
```

but I keep getting this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 71 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 71; columnNumber: 94; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'repositories'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.

I thought I was loading everything correctly...

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.1.xsd">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The namespace for the repositories tag is wrong, just change it to:

```
<repository:repositories base-package="com.site.cmt.repositories" repository-impl-postfix="">
    <repository:repository id="variableRepository" />
</repository:repositories>
```

or set the default namespace of the xml to repository:

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
```

Update: 
I am sorry, I got the namespace wrong, in your case actually you have used `jpa` as the prefix for the correct repository related namespace which is `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa`, so you essentially have to use:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.site.cmt.repositories" repository-impl-postfix="">
    <jpa:repository id="variableRepository" />
</jpa:repositories>
```

But it might be better to just re-assign the repository prefix to the `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa` namespace instead, that is the normal [convention](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition)

Comment: That appears to work... sort of... `The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'repository:repositories'`

Comment: Shouldn't I just need to be able to put `@Repository`?

Comment: Yes @Webnet, I have updated the answer, I had the namespace wrong. You would still need to put this to tell which packages to scan for the Repository components though

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately I'm still having an error :-\ ... `Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]`  The way this is included looks correct...  I've updated my configuration

Comment: @Webnet, can you confirm that you have 1.1.0 RC version of spring-data-jpa jar files in your dependencies list, you are referring to `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.1.xsd` which is part of this version of spring-data-jpa. If not just verify the version of spring-data-jpa that you have, and you can refer to that xsd instead, or leave out version all together: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd`