# Invalid content was found starting with element 'jpa:repository'

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I use this in spring-data-jpa:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd"
default-lazy-init="true">

<jpa:repositories base-package="org.kb" repository-impl-postfix="Impl">
<jpa:repository id="articleDao" repository-impl-ref="articleDaoPlus" /> 
</jpa:repositories>
```

but i got the exception:

nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jpa:repository'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository":include-filter, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository":exclude-filter}' is expected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dispatcher-servlet: Invalid content was found starting with element 'repositories'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600861/dispatcher-servlet-invalid-content-was-found-starting-with-element-repositorie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short if your replace `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd` with `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.1.xsd`, it will solve the problem. But I am not sure you would want to do that.

Reason? Tag `<jpa:repository id="articleDao" repository-impl-ref="articleDaoPlus" />` is removed in the new spring-data-jpa version.

Have a look at the difference between the two xsds i.e.  `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd` and `http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.1.xsd`